# Update Statement using Derived Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to write the following update statement;

```
        UPDATE @eticat
        SET eticat_purchase_total = t.eticat_purchase_total
        FROM (
        SELECT eticat_id, COUNT(eticat_id) as eticat_purchase_count
            FROM etransaction
                INNER JOIN etransaction_item 
                    INNER JOIN etransaction_item_catalog ON eti_eticat_id = eticat_id 
                ON eti_et_id = et_id
        WHERE et_cmc_id = @can_cmc_id 
        GROUP by eticat_id
        ) as t
        WHERE eticat_id = t.eticat_id
```

But it keeps complaining about ambigous columns. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

EDIT: Error Message is "Ambiguous column name 'eticat_id'."

That line is 'WHERE eticat_id = t.eticat_id'

Comment: Can you include the error message?

Comment: You need to alias your inner join tables e.g. `INNER JOIN etransaction_item_catalog eic ON eic.eti_eticat_id = et.eticat_id`

Comment: If two tables contain the same column name, to use it in JOIN, you need to reference the table by ALIAS so the query would know which of the table you are referencing the column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, that's not a CTE; it's a derived table.  Similar, but different :)

Second, you're updating a table variable that's not included in your FROM clause, which is confusing SQL Server.  Try something like:

```
UPDATE x
        SET eticat_purchase_total = t.eticat_purchase_total
        FROM (
        SELECT eticat_id, COUNT(eticat_id) as eticat_purchase_count
            FROM etransaction
                INNER JOIN etransaction_item 
                    INNER JOIN etransaction_item_catalog ON eti_eticat_id = eticat_id 
                ON eti_et_id = et_id
        WHERE et_cmc_id = @can_cmc_id 
        GROUP by eticat_id
        ) as t JOIN @eticat x ON x.eticat_id = t.eticat_id
```

Comment: The fact that the table variable wasn't included in the FROM clause was not confusing SQL Server. The immediate problem was that both `@eticat` and the subselect had an `eticat_id` column, and without a table alias the reference was ambiguous. If you were updating a normal table instead of a table variable, you could simply modify the WHERE clause: `WHERE eticat.eticat_id = t.eticat_id` – and solve the problem. But you can't do that with a table variable: `@eticat.eticat_id` would be invalid syntax in this case. You need to assign an alias to `@eticat`, and your suggestion solves exactly that.

Comment: Sorry for my linguistic shorthand. "confusion" and "ambiguity" are similar enough concepts that I felt that I didn't need to write a more complete statement.  Thankfully you were here to save the day.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I have no problem with your usage of "confusion" vs "ambiguity". My problem is with your statement that the reason for that confusion was because `@eticat` was not in the FROM clause. No, the confusion was caused by an unqualified column name in the WHERE clause, because that name existed in both datasets involved (table variable and subselect).